# Where is relationship between tables in IBM Websphere Portal (IBM Content Manager)?

Tags: db2, websphere

I have a database of IBM Websphere Portal (use IBM DB2, Content Manager) and I'm learning about it. The database include:

- Table ICMUT01641001 for SiteArea
- With each NEWS entry, it will manage in many different tables, same that:

- Table ICMUT01278001 for Rich Text Component (the description, content,... of NEWS)
- Table ICMUT01693001 for Image Component (thumb image of NEWS,...)
  ...

But where is relation ship between these tables? How can I know which content and images belong to which NEWS? and this NEWS belong to which SiteArea?

I can't find the connection between them, I have tried with some key same that ComponentID, ItemID, Compkey,... but not successfully.

Please help me. Thank a lot!

Comment: no one can help me? :(

Comment: Why not study the documentation for your version of Content-Manager and your platform(z/os, linux/unix/windows) ?  Experiment with extporting the data model and other metadata as XML, and load that into an xml viewer (using IBM's supplied xsd file).  This is not a programming question, it is a question about understanding the data-model of your tool, which may be customized for your industry sector or even your company and you can only get such information by studying and interpreting the data model.

Comment: I have read document at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/content-manager/8.5.0?topic=reference-system-control-tables. But I still can not connect data between these tables :(

Comment: As mentioned, you need to export the data model as XML and study that. If you lack the skills , then rent someone with the skills, or use your IBM contacts for consultancy. This is not a matter for stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it